# How do I use setNativeProps in Functional Components? React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am confused on how exactly setNativeProps works for functional components. My code works for class components but I want to change it all into functional components

So I have my functional Component:

`export default function Item(props) {`

in it I have a function called onMoveX

```
    function onMoveX(dx) {
        refs['task'].setNativeProps({ style: { transform: [{ translateX: dx }] } });
    }
```

And in my return I have this.

```
return (
        <View>
            
           <Animated.View ref='task' style={styles.item} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
                <Text style={[styles.text, { flex: 1 }]}> {props.item.text} </Text>
            </Animated.View>

        </View>
    );
```

However, I am getting a Function Components cannot have ref error and I'm stuck on how to fix this issue. I've tried useState but according to many people it is inefficient compared to setNativeProps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional components you can use 'useRef' in the following manner:

```
const taskRef = React.useRef();

function onMoveX(dx) {
    taskRef.current.setNativeProps({ style: { transform: [{ translateX: dx }] } });
}

return (
    <View>
        
       <Animated.View ref={taskRef} style={styles.item} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, { flex: 1 }]}> {props.item.text} </Text>
        </Animated.View>

    </View>
);
```